# Flutter Getx arguments is always returning null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using Getx package in flutter to pass data to another page.
But I am getting null data from the page.

this is my code to get.to

```
Get.to(xreadArticlePage(),transition: Transition.rightToLeft, arguments: 'dataExample');
```

this my code to get data from previous page. data is my data variable. xreadArticlePage is my page to get data.

```
Text(data.toString()),
```

this is to get previous page data. it has a to string because see the data without error for now

```
class xreadArticlePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  var data = Get.arguments;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.back();
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
                Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
                  parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
              child: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                    future: fetch1WpPosts(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                snapshot.data![0]["title"],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Image.network(
                                  snapshot.data![0]["featured_image_large"]),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    snapshot.data![0]["date"],
                                  ),
                                  Text(data.toString()),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Html(data: snapshot.data![0]["content"]),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working very well. I have checked the code. Debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
Get.toNamed(Routes.ADD_ADDRESS_SCREEN, arguments: {
    'address': 'abc',
    'city': 'xyz',
});
```